# Update php version from 5.4.45 in debian wheezy 7.9

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, php

I have been trying to update my system's php from 5.4.45 to 7.0. 
Is it even possible? 
How do i do it?

Following are the results of my commands to update the php version.

```
uname -a

> Linux Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u4 x86_64 GNU/Linux

php --version

>PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini on line 2 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.45-0+deb7u1 (cli) (built: Sep 10 2015 08:34:47)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies


apt-get update

>W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com wheezy Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1487236823 KEYEXPIRED 1487236823 KEYEXPIRED 1487236823
```

apt-get update command is stopped on the above error. I tried to search internet but they are saying that first I have to remove php5. I don't want to take risk. Is there any better solution?

Comment: You might not want to do that, at least not without testing all your vhost in a test server. v7 is largely incompatible with v5.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update the GPG keys to the repo. Run this :

```
apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5
```

And then :

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

You should then be able to install a higher version of `mysql`.

Comment: the error is not showing now. Now how do I update to latest version from 5.4.45? thanks for help

Comment: I edited the answer. Run `apt-get upgrade`

Comment: This is the error now
http://imgur.com/a/PAiXr

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29201696/7499402

Comment: I tried these but still it's showing me the same version 5.4.45. Is it even possible to go beyond this version in debian 7.9?

Comment: I do not think so, all your packages need upgrading, and i think they are at the max version for 7.9. I suggest you do an `apt-get dist-upgrade` if you want to get `php 7`.